# Sequelize: Many to many relationship with two foreign keys

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have two tables related through a relationship table. On the relationship table there are two foreign keys for the same table.

- Factors
- Models
- Models_has_Factors

Models_has_Factors contains foreign keys:

- ref_models_mhf
- ref_factors1_mhf
- ref_factors2_mhf

I want to select models including the factors.
I can't in any way have an implementation where sequelize returns the correct data without the configuration `raw: true`, but this returns multiple objects for the same model, which is not ideal. Is there a way to return only one object for each model, with an array of factors associated to them?

I'll leave my current implementation bellow but I already tried to change the relationship implementation to one using "belongsToMany()" instead but still no luck.

Factor association to models_has_factors

```
Factors.hasMany(models.models_has_factors, {
    foreignKey: { name: "ref_factors1_mhf" },
    as : "ref_factor1"
  })

  Factors.hasMany(models.models_has_factors, {
    foreignKey: { name: "ref_factors2_mhf" },
    as : "ref_factor2"
  })
```

Models_has_Factors associations

```
Models_has_Factors.belongsTo(models.models, {
    foreignKey: { name: "ref_models_mhf" }
  });

  Models_has_Factors.belongsTo(models.factors, {
    foreignKey: { name: "ref_factors1_mhf" },
    as: "factor1"
  });

  Models_has_Factors.belongsTo(models.factors, {
    foreignKey: { name: "ref_factors2_mhf" },
    as: "factor2"
  });
```

Models

```
 Models.hasMany(models.models_has_factors, {
    foreignKey: { name: "ref_models_mhf" }
  });
```

Getter

```
db.models.findAll({
  where: {
    id_models: id,
  },
  include: {
    model: models.models_has_factors,
    include: [{
      model: models.factors,
      as: 'factor1'
    }, {
      model: models.factors,
      as: 'factor2'
    }]
  }
})
```

Comment: Why are there two keys for the "factors"?  If a model needs two (or more) separate "factor" relationships, it can have multiple entries in the relationship table and just one key column.

Comment: @Pointy I need to have both because of the system's logic. Basically models have factors that can be simple or compound, when they're simple only one foreign key is used, when they are compounded both foreign keys are used and we know that the value to use is the difference between the values of both factors

Comment: Right, but you could still do that with a one-column (for factors) in the relationship table. If you get all the relationships for one model, you'll get either one or two (or zero) factor records back. If you do it your way, it will work, but I doubt you can get Sequelize to understand it. Of course doing it with straight SQL would be possible and not really hard, just two inner joins to the factor table, one with one key and one with the other.

Comment: Another option is to re-think the "factors" table so that a single row can store one or two factors, with replicated columns for each as necessary.

Comment: @Pointy thank you!. It is not the focus of the question but I really do need both foreign keys. Imagine I have a model (id 13) with 2 factors, one simple (foreign key 1) and one compound (foreign key 2 minus foreign key 4). If there's only one column, I'd have 3 records: (model 13, factor 1); (model 13, factor 2); (model 13, factor 4).

How would I know that factor 2 and 4 are actually a compounded factor? That in my calculations I should not be using the value of factor 2, nor factor 4, but the difference between both? Understand now why my models is like this?

Comment: @Pointy Other thing is, is not in my interest to rethink table `factors` to have compounded ones since that would increase exponentially the amount of data in the database. I would have to add the combination of all simple factors stored in the table when it's not necessary at all

Comment: @Pointy I guess I'll just have to deal with retrieving mutilple records for the same model, which is terrible for data mapping but I found a workaround. It's just sad that Sequelize doesn't have an easier fix for this

Comment: I don't think the ORM systems I've used could do it directly. The only other idea I have is to use *two* separate relationship tables.

Comment: What's wrong with your current query (indicated at the end of the post)? In this case you will get one `model` object with an array of 2 `models_has_factors`: one would be with factor id 1 and another one would be with factor id 2 and 4.

Comment: @Anatoly nothing's wrong with the query, but if I don't have the config `raw: true` sequelize maps the results into objects. This mapping is incorrect and the data retrieved is just incorrect because it mixes distinct factors. It returns one associated factor on the relationship table (id 1) - that is the first join. But then instead of returning this factor's attributes (from second join) it returns the attributes of factors 2 and 4, which is a huge mess basically

Comment: Ok, Can you add two examples: one is from the query and other one - desired result?